# How to send every request to firebase through my proxy?

Tags: android, firebase

I have an android app. I want every request to firebase got through my proxy.

I tried changing `firebase_url` and `storage_bucket` but seems the only thing taken into account is `project_id`

Here is a piece of my `google-services.json`

```
 {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "123412341234",
    "firebase_url": "https://localhost:8000",
    "project_id": "myproject-asdfa",
    "storage_bucket": "https://localhost:9000"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this somewhere in your app.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "x.x.x.x");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "nnnn");
System.setProperty("com.google.api.client.should_use_proxy", "true");
```